# Reference to Object.prototype.toString.call resulting in 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reference, prototype, this, typeerror

I'm encountering an unusual situation. I store a reference to `Object.prototype.toString.call`, in an attempt to make a shortcut, calling it as the assigned variable results in a TypeError, whereas calling it directly each time does not.

Can anyone explain what is actually happening, as opposed to what I believe I am doing?

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString.call;
toString({}); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Whereas the following works:

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
toString.call({});
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You want `var toString = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is apply not already bound to functions in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23090860/1048572)

Comment: Because `call` expects to be called on the function: `Function.prototype.call.call(Object.prototype.toString, {})` works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're doing

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.toString());
```

`this` or `ThisBinding` in the `toString` function refers to `obj`. In other words, `this = obj`. That is why it works. The method `toString` makes use of `this`, not an argument.

When you do var `toString = Object.prototype.toString.call;`, `this` reference is lost, which is actually being acted upon in the method.

But in the second case, you are just storing the function reference, and by using `Function.call`, you're setting `this` to `{}`, which is why it works, as `this` reference is set to an `Object` be acted upon.

Answer (score 1):

The first case is a reference to unbound `Function.call`, so

```
var unbound_call = Object.prototype.toString.call;
unbound_call({});
// equivalent
Function.prototype.call.call(undefined, {}); // There is no `this`, so undefined
// equivalent
undefined.call({});
```

And that, of course, makes no sense, as `call` expects to be called on a `Function` object, not just any object.

Should be noted that Firefox tells you about this incompatibility:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined

(OK, the `undefined` is still misleading)

As for your second version:

```
var unbound_toString = Object.prototype.toString.call;
unbound_toString.call({})
// equivalent
Object.prototype.toString.call({}); // D'OH
// equivalent
{}.toString();
```

So that is a sound call and works.